# how to add image or text to existing word and excel file using XY coordinate?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, ms-word, phpword

I am trying to add image at particular XY coordniate to my microsoft word doc and excel file using following library

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

I have read the doc completely but i can not able to find how to provide X,Y position to add image in the existing word or excel file ?

here is my code. which is generating new doc but i wanted to add image in the existing doc.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$section->addImage('abc.png',array('width' => 650, 'height' => 365));


header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

can you please suggest any way or solution that how we can do it? Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code what did you do?

Comment: @kingan ok i have added code in the questions please check thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set image location:

[here more information about addImage](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#image-style)

```
$section->addImage($src, [$style]);
```

Like you did with `['width' => 650]`

You can add marginLeft as array key it will be your x value:

```
$section->addImage('abc.png',array('width' => 650, 'height' => 365, 'marginLeft': 100));
```

Comment: ok also how can i use existing word file to add image? because my code is only working with new word file creating,

Comment: It will be harder to deal becuase where do you put the image etc.

Comment: my main issue is that i have existing doc. i want to add the image it to the existing doc with given XY Position.

Comment: let me know if you have any example ? Thanks